# Set div with an ID grit template after clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have a question. I have a simple chekcbox that in html looks like

```
<label class="container__control--checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="presentation_full_screen" class="container__control" onchange="_handleMainLayout()" />
    <span>CLICK</span>
 </label>
```

So when I click checkbox I fire up this type script:

```
   _handleMainLayout() {
        const layoutContainer = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("main_layout");
        const hideCommunicationCheckbox <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("presentation_full_screen");
        if (hideCommunicationCheckbox.checked) {
            layoutContainer.removeAttribute("style");
        } else {
            layoutContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr";
        }
    }
```

So what id does it sets template on main layout (id: main_layout) from 1 column to 2 columns depends on this if checkbox is selected, and well it works.

But I was wondering, there are those selectors in css :checked and not(). So thing is, element with id main layout is way up DOM tree, and question can I somehow get that element using those selectors or any any other css/scss trick and toggle this grid-template-colum?

something like

```
.container__control :checked {
   //get div with ID and set its grid-template-colum
 }
.container__control :not(:checked) {
   //get div with ID and set its grid-template-colum
}
```

Or am I left with only JS solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use CSS only to do that. The "trick" is where to insert the `<input>` element. Thanks to label attribute `for` you don't need to have `<input>` and `<label>` near one from the other. However `<input>` must be placed before `#main_layout` and on same DOM "branch" in order to use General (~) or adjacent (+) sibling combinator.

```css
#main_layout {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

:checked + #main_layout {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkox">Click me</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkox" hidden>
<div id="main_layout"></div>
```

no need for `:not()` in this case